# I have two folders filled with files which have identical names but different content. How can I match them to copy data from one file to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two folders filled with similarly named excel files but in different templates. One of the templates (Newer) is blank, while the old template contains all the data.

The patterns between template A and template B are consistent - I know which cell in A goes to which cell in B, but I'm not sure how to create the macro in VBA to effectively process all of the files in one go.

I've so far created two File system objects, one per folder - but I'm not sure how to get it to pull up the identical file from the other folder to start the cloning process.

To avoid excel having issues opening files of the same name, the newer templates have a 3 character suffix at the end.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
    Set picker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    picker.Show
    Set fldrs = picker.SelectedItems
    fpath1 = fldrs(1)

Set picker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    picker.Show
    Set fldrs = picker.SelectedItems
    fpath2 = fldrs(1)

Dim fso1 As Object
Dim vfolder1 As Object
Dim fso2 As Object
Dim vfolder2 As Object

Set fso1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set vfolder1 = fso1.GetFolder(fpath1)

Set fso2 = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set vfolder2 = fso2.GetFolder(fpath2)

For Each vfile In vfolder1.Files
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Firstly, always use **Option Explicit**, it is your friend and can help to eliminate issues that are generally relatively minor but hard to investigate. Second, you don't need to create 2 instances of `File System Object`. Single instance will suffice. You can use that same instance of `FSO` to get files in both folders. Now to your issue, so you want to capture the data from one file (A) to second file (B) based on matching the file names that exist in a third file?

Comment: Hi! Good to know about the FSO, I'll see if I can make it work. A and B are already named similarly - For example, Datafile1.xlsx and Datafile1_v2.xlsx.

Comment: So you want to bring all data over from `Datafile1 over to `Datafile2`? can you provide screen prints of the older template and the new template? it will help

Comment: I sadly can't as it's not public data.
I've managed to loop the process in a different way:

`Set fso1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set vfolder1 = fso1.GetFolder(fpath1)

Set fso2 = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set vfolder2 = fso2.GetFolder(fpath2)

For Each vfile1 In vfolder1.Files
    For Each vfile2 In vfolder2.Files
    
    

    
    
    If Left(vfile1.Name, Len(vfile1.Name) - 5) = Left(vfile2.Name, Len(vfile2.Name) - 8) Then
    
        
        DoEvents
        Workbooks.Open (vfile1)
        Workbooks.Open (vfile2)`

Comment: Alex, @Zac is not asking for the data, he is asking for your templates for the old and new format. With out knowing how the data is formatted on your source and destination worksheets your question is to vague to provide a workable solution.

Comment: Assuming that Document A and B are not identically named couldn't you just use: `Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\" & FolderAorB & ":" & LoopingExampleName & ".xlsx"`.

Comment: When you say _similarly_ do you mean they have `_v?` appended to the end of the filename, or might one say `DataFile1.xlsx` and one say `DataFileOne_xlsx`?  Code isn't that good at figuring out `similar`.  Also - are all files represented in the new folder?  If that's the case you only need to look at one folder and know that the other folder contains a file with that name (and _v1 appended to the end).

Comment: @GMalc The template itself contains sensitive information. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: @EmilyAlden I needed to make sure they opened in their matched pairs, which i did with the "IF left..." statement.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Appended, I created them with the suffix in place. If i opened only one folder, wouldn't it stop me copying individual cell data into the files in the other folder? Sorry, not seeing the train of thought due to my inexperience.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of the accepted answer, except that I was assuming the file does exist in the _target_ folder so would open it using the expected file name rather than using a `For Each searched in target` loop to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the file names always *start* the same ("the newer templates have a 3 character suffix ***at the end***"), you can just strip the path and the extension from the file names with [`GetBaseName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getbasename-method) and compare them to see if the target file name starts with the source file name:

```
With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim source As Folder, target As Folder

    Set source = .GetFolder(fpath1)
    Set target = .GetFolder(fpath2)

    Dim item As File, fileName As String
    For Each item In source.Files
        'Get the filename without path or extension.
        fileName = .GetBaseName(item)
        Dim searched As File
        For Each searched In target
            'Does the file start with fileName?
            If InStr(1, .GetBaseName(item), fileName) = 1 Then
                'Files match, do your thing here.
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With
```

Note that this is early bound.  If you're insistant on not adding a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime (there's almost never a reason not to), just change the early bound variables to `Object` and replace the `New Scripting.FileSystemObject` with `CreateObject`.

Comment: Thanks! This looks a lot cleaner than what I wrote. I'm not super confident in my VBA so I tend to use what I've seen before, especially with FSO's.